# Phonegap compass plugin not working

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am trying to get a compass function working on my app with no success.  Judging by the errors I am inclined to think that the plugin is not being added or the device is not ready.  But as far as I can tell I have done both things.  I am using phonegap build, so the only code I use to include it is:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" version="0.3.9" />
```

Which as far as I know is all that is required.  When I click on the plugins tab in the phonegap build page for my app it shows up as being there.

```
watchDirection = null;
//Phonegap is ready
var whenDeviceReady = function(){
        console.log("deviceready");
        console.log(navigator.compass);
        var findMyDirection = function(){
            console.log("find my heading fired");
            watchDirection = navigator.compass.watchHeading(
            //onSuccess
            function(heading){
                console.log(heading);
                var magnetDirection = heading.magneticHeading;
                $("#movingCompass").css("transform", "rotate(" + magnetDirection + "deg)");
            },
            //onError
            function(error){
                console.log('code: '    + error.code  +'  message: ' + error.message);
            },
            //Update Frequency
            { frequency: 1000});
        }

        findMyDirection();
}

//Wait for phonegap to load
document.addEventListener("deviceready", whenDeviceReady, false);
```

The above code works as expected with the exception of the compass object.  The `console.log(navigator.compass);` returns as `undefined`.  And there is an error on the line which includes `watchDirection = navigator.compass.watchHeading(` saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'watchHeading' of undefined`.

It gets listed in the phonegap build list of installed plugins, and I already have the geolocation working with the same code format I have posted above.

Comment: Give this a shot: `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" source="plugins.cordova.io" />` though they do not recommend that repository since it is going EOL in October 2015.  Better practice would be to use npm: `<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" source="npm" />`

Comment: Didn't help unfortunately! Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Marty.H, I have working demos here: http://codesnippets.altervista.org/examples/phonegap/demos/PUBLIC.Apps.html Go to the lower half of the page and try pre-built app, *Phonegap-Compass-Test*. If it works, the top half of the page has the links to github where you can get the source code. --Jesse

Comment: Thanks!  I tried your example and it worked, so I have been swapping 1 file at a time to try find where my problem is.  After that didn't work I finally realized I needed to reinstall rather than just rehydrating it.

Comment: Okay. Some people like a *divid and conquer* technique. I prefer the, *working with known goods*. You just saw the benefit of *working with known goods*. Since my demo program worked for you, that meant the hardware was good, and the API was good. So that left everything else, which you quickly found. Best of Luck in your future ventures.